Migration not adding, Screen hangs after "Build succeeded" message in Visual Studio
I'm encountering an issue in Visual Studio where, after a successful build, the screen hangs and I'm unable to add migrations. The specific steps I'm taking are as follows:

I initiate a build process for my project.
The build completes successfully, and I see the "Build succeeded" message.
Immediately after, when I attempt to add a migration, Visual Studio hangs and becomes unresponsive.

I've tried the following troubleshooting steps, but the problem persists:

Restarting Visual Studio and my computer.
Clearing the NuGet cache and restoring packages.
Ensuring all project dependencies and packages are up-to-date.
Running Visual Studio as an administrator.
Checking for any background processes or tasks that might be interfering.
Reviewing the Output and Error List windows for any hidden issues or warnings.

Has anyone else encountered this issue or have any suggestions on how to resolve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Do you have any error logs output from any window?Also it would be nice if you could try adding migration with dotnet CLI add-Migration command and see if it can work?

No there is no error showing, Yes but as per your suggestion, Its working fine with dotnet cli. Thanks for the support.
